# Jetpack compose - Why expand() is internal in ModalBottomSheet?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I'm working with `ModalBottomSheet`, what it caught my attention is that sheetState has 2 public methods, `show()` and `hide()` for `show()` the documentation says that

```
 /**
     * Show the bottom sheet with animation and suspend until it's shown. If the sheet is taller
     * than 50% of the parent's height, the bottom sheet will be half expanded. Otherwise it will be
     * fully expanded.
     *
     * @throws [CancellationException] if the animation is interrupted
     */
    suspend fun show() {
        val targetValue = when {
            hasHalfExpandedState -> HalfExpanded
            else -> Expanded
        }
        animateTo(targetValue = targetValue)
    }
```

But there is a problem, if we just use `.show()` to the `sheetState` we will end up with a half scrolled bottom sheet at some times, this leads to inconsistencies with my current UI

After digging into the file I found out that we have a `expand()` internal method , just what I needed

```
/**
 * Fully expand the bottom sheet with animation and suspend until it if fully expanded or
 * animation has been cancelled.
 * *
 * @throws [CancellationException] if the animation is interrupted
 */
internal suspend fun expand() = animateTo(Expanded)
```

But this happens to be internal and cannot be accessed from outside

Is there a way to execute that state with `sheetState` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`skipHalfExpanded` has been added to the `ModalBottomSheetState` constructor [in 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.2.0-alpha01). This will ensure calling `show()` always shows the expanded state.

```
val modalBottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
        initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
        skipHalfExpanded = true
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there is a way of doing it, we can replace

```
modalBottomSheetState.show()
```

to

```
modalBottomSheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded)
```

this way we are sure that when we show the modal it will be fully expanded.

I don't know why that method is not marked as public for the API, hopefully we can include that in the next API changes in `ModalBottomSheet`

Comment: now animate.to is also internal in material3:1.1.0-alpha08

Comment: so, now, expaned is public or it keeps it internal also? if so, there is no way of fully expand it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75962702/sheetscaffoldstate-animateto-method-is-internal-and-cant-be-accessed/75962715#75962715