# SheetScaffoldState animateTo method is internal and can't be accessed

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Now in the new API, the animateTo method isn't available to be used. How to animateTo to a state smoothly with a custom animation time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now we can use AnimationSpec for default animation time.

```
val animationSpec = remember { 
    Animatable(0f)
        .run {
            TweenSpec<Float>(durationMillis = 300)
        }
}
```

and then

```
val sheetScaffoldState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue = ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden,
    skipHalfExpanded = true,
    animationSpec = animationSpec
)
```

and now simple call show() or hide(), like this

```
scope.launch {
        sheetScaffoldState.hide()
    }
```